# Installing Maven and creating a maven project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am new to using maven project and i am trying to create a maven project and i followed the instructions to create one in eclipse and i gave the groupId and artifact id to it and clicked Finish, for which it gave me an error stating

> "No marketplace entries found to handle
>   maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile in Eclipse.  Please see Help for
>   more information."

For this issue i tried googling and stack overflow and i saw people asking other people to change the installation directory of maven inside

> Window-> Preferences -> Maven-> Installation

I tried that and tried to update the maven project but still i have some errors, i am not able to setup my project, Could someone please help?
I am attaching the errors herewith. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can try to install maven globaly. follow the steps.

1. Download maven from [maven download link](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)
2. Create or export M2_HOME="MAVEN ROOT LOCATION". Ex. : **E:\SoftwareRepo\building tools\apache-maven-3.5.2**
3. Create  or export MAVEN bin folder location to PATH variable.
   For example: **E:\SoftwareRepo\building tools\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin**
4. Open terminal or cmd and run **mvn --version** to confirm maven is installed or not.

Then go to eclipse. and setup project.follow this steps

1. Import existing maven project or create a maven project
2. Goto project explorer and Right click on your pom.xml
3. then select Run As maven install.
4. and then what you want.

Hope it will serve your purpose. You can download a sample spring boot project from [sample spring boot project](https://start.spring.io/)

Or you can run a maven project from terminal or cmd. Just goto project root folder and then run a maven task like **maven clean install** .
Happy Coding :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If  a Maven project is configured to use ecj compiler, the following errors appear when importing the project into eclipse:

- No marketplace entries found to handle maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile in Eclipse.  Please see Help for more information.
- No marketplace entries found to handle maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile in Eclipse.  Please see Help for more information.

A fix should be trivial.

http://git.eclipse.org/c/m2e/m2e-core.git/tree/org.eclipse.m2e.jdt/lifecycle-mapping-metadata.xml reads:

```
    <parameters>
      <compilerId>javac</compilerId>
    </parameters>
```

It should read:

```
    <parameters>
      <compilerId>javac</compilerId>
      <compilerId>eclipse</compilerId>
    </parameters>
```

Reproducible: Always

Steps to Reproduce:
1. Unpack example zip provided
2. Try to import it to Eclipse: File->Import->Maven->Existing Maven Projects

Answer (score 0):

First install `Java` and then create the `maven` project.

Install the stable `Java` version in the system.

If `Java` is not installed then these types of errors will be displayed.

> No marketplace entries found to handle
> maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile in Eclipse.

Take a look at `Help` for more information.